# Can I pass a generic Type dynamically in Java?

Tags: java, jackson, frameworks

I have this java class as -

```java
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Dummy {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

I have this JSON as -

```
[
    [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name": "John"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "name": "Maxwell"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name": "Bryan"
        }
    ]
]
```

I am currently developing a framework and I would not be knowing what would be the type of the collection that JSON fits in.
I am currently using Jackson library to parse the JSON to Java object.
The main thing is I don't know the type at compile time.
I would like to fit the json into **List<List<Dummy>>** but I don't know the type before hand. Is there any way to pass the generic in runtime?

1. `Object object  = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Collection.class);`
2. `List<List<Dummy>> l = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<List<Dummy>>>(){});`

In the first approach I am passing the **Collection.class** but it converts the json to List<LinkedHashmap<String, String>> which I don't want.

But, In the second approach I get the actual conversion but the problem is I don't know the type at compile time.

Can I anyhow inject the generic dynamically or any other approach I would tackle this?

Any suggestion/help would be very helpful for me :)

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile time, how will you write code which uses the data you read from the JSON? You need to explain in more detail what you are trying to do.

Comment: @tgdavies As I have said, I am a framework developer. So, How can I get the actual type from a Parameter and can pass it into the generics of the TypeReference?

Comment: You could require that the caller who is providing the JSON also provides a TypeReference, or something you can map to a TypeReference.

Comment: Basically I have a method which has a parameter List<List<Dummy>> object. Now, I want this parameter type as List<List<Dummy>> to put it in the TypeReference<List<List<Dummy>>>and then I want to take the JSON and transform the JSON into the above type. How to do it in runtime?